# Android oval shape button not showing shadow at buttom

Tags: android

[Image of keeping the button above check box the shadow shows at bottom of oval shape button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr6V0.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/idroot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MedicineInfoActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/ll3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_extra"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll2"
        android:indeterminateTint="#1a09d6"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/mname"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progressbar">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_medicine_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
                    android:hint="Course title"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cal"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til5"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til2">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_medicine_start_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
                    android:hint="Start date"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cal"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til6"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til5">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_medicine_end_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
                    android:hint="End date"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/clock"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til8"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til5">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_time"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="Taking time" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/note"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til9"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til5">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_comment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:maxHeight="200dp"
                    android:maxWidth="200dp"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:hint="Comment" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="176dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_bold"
                android:text="SET" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Use notifications" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

when keeping the button below check box the shadow doesnot shows at bottom of oval shape button.

[when keeping the button below check box the shadow doesnot shows at bottom of oval shape button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wka50.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/idroot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MedicineInfoActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/ll3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_extra"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_regular"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll2"
        android:indeterminateTint="#1a09d6"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/mname"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progressbar">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_medicine_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
                    android:hint="Course title"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cal"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til5"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til2">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_medicine_start_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
                    android:hint="Start date"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cal"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til6"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til5">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_medicine_end_date"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
                    android:hint="End date"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:editable="false" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/clock"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til8"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til5">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_time"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="Taking time" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/note"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/til9"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til5">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_comment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="130dp"
                    android:maxHeight="200dp"
                    android:maxWidth="200dp"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:hint="Comment" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Use notifications" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="176dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_bold"
                android:text="SET" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Button background="@drawable/button_background" file contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp" />


    <gradient android:startColor="#44E4C7"
        android:endColor="#44B8E2"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: did you try giving some margin bottom to your button ? this might happed because your layout has fixed sized and the shadow gets cut off in that

Comment: Try adding `android:elevation="12dp"` (or any other value!)

Comment: Glad to help brother.